# input string is not in a correct format c#

Tags: c#, sql, types, textbox, int

I want to multiply the text value and combo box value and display it in a orderprice textbox 
the data types that I use in sql are 'float' for all of these

```
private void cb_oqty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int orderprice;
    int proprice=Convert.ToInt16(txt_oprice.Text);
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt16(cb_oqty.SelectedItem);

    orderprice = proprice * quantity;
    txt_orderprice.Text = Convert.ToString(orderprice);
    txt_orderprice.Update();                                
}
```

Comment: You need to put breakpoints and debug individual line. Only that way you can find out which statement is throwing the exception.

Comment: I think when combo fill all items that particular time it throws exception.
it comes before selecting combo value or after selecting?

Comment: i am getting error on this line  int proprice=Convert.ToInt16(txt_oprice.Text);

Comment: @AlyGoreja
it comes after selecting combo value or before?
where you give data to combo box?? i.e in form load?

Comment: when i select value from combo box after it and it does not show the value tgrows an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use int.TryParse to see if the text can be converted first. That error seems to point to text not being able to be converted to int.

```
int orderprice = 0;
int proprice = 0;
int quantity = 0;

if (int.TryParse(txt_oprice.Text, out proprice) && int.TryParse(cb_oqty.SelectedValue.ToString(), out quantity))
{
    // It was assigned.
    orderprice = proprice * quantity;
}
else
{
    //Error
}
```

Also the cb_oqty.SelectedItem will not convert to an int as it is an Object. you need to use SelectedValue.

Comment: it is giving error at int.tryparse(cb_oqty.selectedvalue, out quantity)

Comment: int.TryParse(cb_oqty.SelectedValue.ToString(), out quantity). It needs to be SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: error object rerference not set to be an instance of an object at tryparse line

Comment: and after i select value from combo box

Comment: Put a break point on the if statement. View in the debugger watch what the combo box values have.

Comment: Try this then int.TryParse(cb_oqty.SelectedItem.ToString(), out quantity). Check what value is SelectedItem also

Comment: thanks james it worked with selected item thanks alot Appriciated (y)

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL datattype is float, your C# datatype should be float as well:

```
    private void cb_oqty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var proprice = Convert.ToSingle(txt_oprice.Text);
        var quantity = Convert.ToSingle(cb_oqty.SelectedItem);

        var orderprice = proprice * quantity;
        txt_orderprice.Text = orderprice.ToString();

        // this does not do what you think it does. You can remove this line.
        txt_orderprice.Update();
    }
```

Better would be using the [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method.